# Searching for specific data, and copying it to current document

Tags: vba, excel

I have created one macro to list all of the files that I need to grab data from in the first column of an Excel spreadsheet. Is it possible to search each of the files in the column and locate specific data using key words. For example the first column of my master document is:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

I want to search file1 then file2... for a keywords "alpha" "beta" "gamma" and then copy the numbers below those cells into a table in the master document. Is this possible, if so what avenue should I go down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i would like to give another answer but, @RickSportel give a very good advice.

Hope this will help.

```
Sub findDataIntoFiles()

    Dim r
    Dim findValues() As String 'heres goes all the values you want to search
    Dim Wrbk As Workbook 'to store every workbook
    Dim This As Workbook 'to store this workbook, where you got the macro
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'to store every sheet of the workbooks
    Dim i
    Dim tmp
    Dim counter
    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstAddress
    Dim rng As Range 'the range with the files full path of the file names
                     'Not just the names
                     'or
                     'if all the files are in the same folder, you can put the path
                     'on a var, and concatenate the path with each file name

    ReDim findValues(1 To 3) 'here redim the var, but you can declare it with the capacity you want
    findValues(1) = "Alpha"
    findValues(2) = "Beta"
    findValues(3) = "Gamma"
    counter = 0

    r = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'to search the last row of the data with the workbooks names
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, 1)) 'all the data is in column A
    Set This = ThisWorkbook 'storing this workbook

    For Each tmp In rng 'run this for every cell with the workbooks names
        Workbooks.Open tmp 'the open the workbook
        Set Wrbk = ActiveWorkbook 'store it ot use it
        For Each sht In Wrbk.Worksheets 'here, for every sheet inside the workbook that i opened
            For i = 1 To 3 'the qty of data inside findValues var'for every data inside the var
                With sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
                'find inside the cells A1 and the LastCell of the sheet
                Set c = .Find(findvalue(i), LookIn:=xlFormulas) 'you can chage ir to "xlValues"
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        firstAddress = c.Address
                        Do
                            'This.Activate'go back to the macro workbook and store the data found
                            tmp.Offset(0, 1).Value = tmp.Value 'the name/fullpath/path of the workbook
                            tmp.Offset(0, 2).Value = sht.Name & "\" & c.Address 'Sheet and address of the cell
                            Set c = .FindNext(c) 'go to the next one
                            counter = counter + 1 'and index for the columns where you will store the data
                        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        Next sht
    Next tmp
End Sub
```

And this is basic, you need to itenerate over the cells with the workbooks names, if there is the full path just take that, but if not take the path (directory) where the files are and then concatenate and open the workbooks with [Workbook.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx)

And go over every sheet of each worbook, and find the data you want.

**Edit #1**
As you ask in the comments this could give you the next cells where you found the seach string

```
c.Address ===> Gives you the address (string) of the found cell ex. $G$4
c.offset(2,2).address ===> gives you the cell moving two rows and two columns from `c` and returns $I$6. If you put negative numbers you rest rows and columns.
```

Comment: Hi Elbert, thanks so much for the help! One question on the code, I understand most of it but was wondering where to alter which cells you take relative to the keywords. Say I find alpha but want to take 2 cells to the right instead? Is it even possible in short to have different conditions for each keyword?

Comment: As you can see `c.Address` returns the address of the cell that has the `"alpha` string. Then if you use `c.offset(row_Num , col_Num)` you can get the cells you want.

Comment: ah, thank you so much! :) how did you get to be so proficient with vba?

Comment: Hi Elbert, Sorry to bring up an old topic but i have an additional question on how I might be able to adapt your code to alter the output. Would it be possible to specify different output locations for different values of "i" in FindValues(i)? So that for example for "alpha" the output is in column C but then for Bravo, the output is in Column D? I have tried a couple of things but to no success as the target locations are within the loop?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Just use Workbooks.Open as documented here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx
As a filename, just pass the cell value that holds said filename.

Very basic example: Say cell A1 on Worksheets(1) holds the filepath + filename of the file you want to open.

```
Sub OpenFile()
Dim wb as WorkBook
Dim fRange as range

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Worksheets(1).Range("A1").value)
With wb
    set fRange = .Sheets(1).Range("1:1").find("Alpha") 'Assuming Alpha is a header in row 1
    'Do stuff with the cells below the found range
End With

Set fRange = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

You might want to store the ActiveWorkbook / ActiveSheet / Any reference to your mastersheet in a variable as well in order to make sure you can copy-paste from the right place to the right place.